# How to left-align a ordered and unordered list in HTML?

Tags: html, css

When i create list in html it moves up a little to the right. How can i align it all the way to the left?

```
My name is:

     1. John
     2. Jack
     3. Jones
```

But I would like it like this:

```
My name is:
1. John
2. Jack
3. Jones
```

Gr. Peter

Answer (score 0):

This is because `<ol>`, like other elements has some user agent stylesheet applied by default.

You can play around with padding and margin, to adjust it as you like.

You can try something like:

```
padding-left: 0;
margin-left: 20px;
```